# How to add external link value to selected option in html

Tags: html, css

I want to add 3 diffrent hyperlink to selected option, submit button should take the value from selected option and only redirect to that option. Here is a html select code -

```
<div>
```

1 Email Account`<option>5 Email Accounts</option><option>10 Email Accounts</option>`15 Email Accounts`<a href="#" class="read">sign up<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div>`

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant language tags.

Comment: ok sure, buddy plz help me with this issue

Comment: Jsfiddle - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uew54xag/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this working code.

```js
    $(function(){
   $('button').click( function(){
  if($('#dynamic_select').val()== '5EmailAccounts') {
   alert('5EmailAccounts');
   window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
  }
  if($('#dynamic_select').val()== '10EmailAccounts') {
   alert('10EmailAccounts');
   window.location = 'http://www.youtube.com';
  }
  if($('#dynamic_select').val()== '15EmailAccounts') {
   alert('15EmailAccounts');
   window.location = 'https://in.yahoo.com/';
  }
   });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="5EmailAccounts">5 Email Accounts</option>
  <option value="10EmailAccounts">10 Email Accounts</option>
  <option value="15EmailAccounts">15 Email Accounts</option>
</select>

<button>Submit</button>
```